# how to print in ML

Tags: sml, ml, abstract-data-type

I've searched and found several people asking this question, but I can't find an explicit answer.
How can I print a non-string in sml?

For example if I have an instance of an ADT, i.e., of a type declared by `datatype`, and I would like to print the value for debugging.    Am I responsible for writing a function which converts such an object to a string, and then print the string?   Or is there some printer library I should use?   Or is there some sort of printObject or toString function?

Also how can I print other non-string objects such as `true` and `false`?

It would appear that sml knows how to print such objects, because when I compile a file using C-l in emacs, I see output such as the following, showing that sml does know how to print the values.

```
[opening /Users/jimka/Repos/mciml/ex1.1.sml]
type key = string
datatype tree = LEAF | TREE of tree * string * tree
val empty = LEAF : tree
val insert = fn : key * tree -> tree
val member = fn : key * tree -> bool
val t1 = TREE (LEAF,"a",LEAF) : tree
val t2 = TREE (LEAF,"a",TREE (LEAF,"c",LEAF)) : tree
val t3 = TREE (LEAF,"a",TREE (TREE (LEAF,"b",LEAF),"c",LEAF)) : tree

val it = true : bool

val it = () : unit
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I print a non-string in sml?

As I understand it, this is not possible (in a portable way). Depending on the implementation you're using it may expose a function that does this.

> Also how can I print other non-string objects such as `true` and `false`?

Many types with corresponding basis library structures (e.g., `int` and `Int`) have a `toString` function, so you could print a bool `b` via `print (Bool.toString b)` and similarity with `Int.toString` for an `int`.

Some implementation specific thoughts:

For PolyML, you can use the function `PolyML.print` to print values of arbitrary types (though you may need to explicitly type annotate; the type of the argument should not have any type variables).

For SML/NJ, you might try taking a look at the approach discussed here https://sourceforge.net/p/smlnj/mailman/message/21897190/, though this seems like more trouble than it's worth.

For MLton, I'm not aware of anything like a polymorphic function, but they have a couple guides on implementing printf or similar.

It looks like Moscow ML supports a function `Meta.printVal`, but only in an interactive session. I'm not sure what support SML# has for this sort of thing.

> Am I responsible for writing a function which converts such an object to a string, and then print the string?

Generally speaking, yes.

> It would appear that sml knows how to print such objects

Depending on your SML implementation this is enabled because the REPL has access to more information than a program normally might. For instance, SML/NJ is able to do this because the REPL has access to type information not available elsewhere (for a source, see John Reppy's statements in the linked mailman thread).

You might also find MLton's [TypeIndexedValues](http://mlton.org/TypeIndexedValues#_signature) example page helpful for this sort of thing, though I haven't closely examined it for quality myself.